# ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation crashes on emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I'm using ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation to manage the transition from one Activity to another in some cases.

When I try on an emulator (API 16 or 23) it doesn't work and the entire emulator freezes. If I set `options` to `null` the app works.

Any idea why? On Android Studio, I get a warning as I'm using `android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear_out_slow_in"` as it's not supported on API under 21. But I expect this field to be ignored if not supported, plus it doesn't work either on the emulator under API 23 so I don't think this is the issue.

**Here is the method I call**

```
/**
 * @param destActivity Activity we want to launch
 * @param activity Current activity
 */
private <T> void goToNextActivity(Class<T> destActivity, Activity activity) {

    Bundle options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(activity,
            R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, destActivity);
    activity.startActivity(intent, options);

    activity.finish(); // Finishes the current Activity
}
```

**fade_in.xml**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear_out_slow_in" />
```

**fade_out.xml**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replying to my younger self, five months later:

As suspected, the issue was the interpolator. I removed it and added the `fade_in` `fade_out` implementation described in the question in an `anim-v21` folder.